# init vs wp_loaded: Difference with example?

Tags: wordpress

I understand **init** is fired when most of the WordPress is loaded but headers are not sent and **wp_loaded** is fired when most of WordPress is loaded and headers are sent.

Can someone please explain with an example that what will and will not work with these hooks with a use case scenario that explains and clarifies their difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per my understanding, `init` hook implies that WP core is loaded but 3rd party content (e.g. themes, plugins, etc.) is *only starting to load*. Hook `wp_loaded` means that core *and* 3rd party content is loaded.

> Can someone please explain with an example that what will and will not work with these hooks with a use case scenario that explains and clarifies their difference?

I guess if you want to override 3rd party plugin, you need to use `wp_loaded` unless the plugin itself creates its own specific "loaded" hook.

If you want to somehow alter default styles and scripts, you need to use `wp_loaded` as they are not loaded when `init` fires.

---

Please see technical clarification below:

**init** is run *before* **wp_loaded**:

- `init`
- `register_sidebar`
- `wp_register_sidebar_widget`
- `wp_default_scripts`
- `wp_default_styles`
- `admin_bar_init`
- `add_admin_bar_menus`
- `wp_loaded`

source: [WP Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference)

Additional insight for `init` hook:

> Most of WP is loaded at this stage, and the user is authenticated. WP continues to load on the ‘init’ hook that follows (e.g. widgets), and many plugins instantiate themselves on it for all sorts of reasons (e.g. they need a user, a taxonomy, etc.).

source: [WP Developer](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/init/)

Additional insight for `wp_loaded` hook:

> This hook is fired once WP, all plugins, and the theme are fully loaded and instantiated.

source: [WP Developer](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_loaded/)

EDIT: also, bear in mind that `wp_loaded` is executed *before* `admin_init` (in case of admin-page request)